# Ansible - Issue in writing output to a csv file

Tags: ansible

Ansible version - 2.9

Facing issue in writing output to a csv file, its not writing the output consistently into the file.

Having an inventory file with three server IPs,  script will execute command to check the disk space of each server and writing the output to a csv file.

Sometimes its writing all the three server details into the file, sometimes its writing only one or two server details into the file.

```yaml
  - hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    gather_facts: False
    vars:
      filext: ".csv"
    tasks:
      - name: get the username running the deploy
        local_action: command whoami
        register: username_on_the_host

      - name: get current dir
        local_action: command pwd
        register: current_dir

      - name: create dir
        file: path={{ current_dir.stdout }}/HCT state=directory

      - name: Set file path here
        set_fact:
            file_path: "{{ current_dir.stdout }}/HCT/HCT_check{{ filext }}"

      - name: Creates file
        file: path={{ file_path }}  state=touch

# Writing to a csv file

    - hosts:
      - masters
    become: false
    vars:
      disk_space: "Able to get disk space for the CM {{ hostname }} "
      disk_space_error: "The server {{ hostname  }} is down for some reason. Please check manually."
      disk_space_run_status: "{{disk_space}}"
      cur_date: "{{ansible_date_time.iso8601}}"

    tasks:
      - name: runnig command to get file system which are occupied 
        command: bash -c "df -h | awk '$5>20'"
        register: disk_space_output
        changed_when: false
        ignore_errors: True
        no_log: True

      - name: Log the task get list of file systems with space occupied 
        lineinfile:
           dest: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['file_path'] }}"
           line: "File system occupying disk space, {{ hostname }}, {{ ip_address }}, {{ cur_date }}"
           insertafter: EOF
           state: present
        delegate_to: localhost
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the task "Log the task get list of file systems with space occupied" is executed in parallel for the 3 servers, so you're having concurrent writing problems.

One solution is to use the `serial` keyword at play level with a value of `1`, this way, all the tasks will be executed for each server one at a time.

```yaml
- hosts:
  - masters
become: false
serial: 1
vars:
[...]
```

Another solution is to have the task executed for only 1 server but looping over the results of all servers by using `hostvars`:

```yaml
  - name: Log the task get list of file systems with space occupied 
    lineinfile:
       dest: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['file_path'] }}"
       line: "File system occupying disk space, {{ hostvars[item].hostname }}, {{ hostvars[item].ip_address }}, {{ hostvars[item].cur_date }}"
       insertafter: EOF
       state: present
    run_once: True
    loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"  # Looping over all hosts of the play
    delegate_to: localhost
```